# Qt WebEngine Run Multiple Instances in Different Threads

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I'm new to QT and its threading concept, so I have a question about [WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html#articles-and-guides) and managing threads.

What I want to do with my application is to load different websites by using multiple instances of WebEngines in different threads on the background and based on a user action, show a browser with already loaded WebEngine content.

Is it possible to manage WebEngine instances in a thread other than main QT application thread?

**Edit:** Here is the whole story of my problem, my application is somewhat related to different websites. For example, when user makes a search in my application, set of results is shown from these websites. If user wants to select a result, my application is supposed to redirect user to the source website of that result and execute some Javascript code in order to navigate user to the exact page that he/she wants to see. However, only the last step of executing Javascript is based on user action, the rest of the routine is identical and doesn't change based on user actions at all. So in order to make this routine much faster, I want to keep all these websites loaded (max. 6 websites) and navigated to a page by the executed JS code. When user selects a result, instead of loading website and execute JS code, I want to bring back the already loaded web browser and only execute JS code that is related to user input.

As a side note, these websites are actually single page applications, so there is no dedicated URL for a page to redirect user, I have to go to the home page and manually execute JS code to navigate which page I wanted to visit.

Comment: You can not, and I do not see the reason you want to do that. QtWebEngineView is a GUI, and the GUI can not run on another thread, besides they are made to work correctly in the event-loop. What advantages would I have to execute it in another thread? Many when we know that they are the threads we want to apply in everything even when it is not necessary, and that is called abuse. The task of the threads in a GUI is to prevent the main thread from being blocked, and I think that handling many QWebEngineView does not block anything.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Maybe you could explain more about what you're trying to do and why, rather than this particular solution?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added a detailed explanation of my problem. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @MertAkozcan And in what part do you need new threads? Why do you want to use it?